# How do physics engines model angular velocity and angular acceleration (in 3D)

Tags: 3d, game-physics, physics-engine

I have been looking around for answers to this question and I can't find a straight answer.
It seems the word online is that angular velocity is stored as a vector, where the direction is the axis of rotation and the length is the rate of rotation.
That makes some sense but it completely neglects how you actually work with it.
So there are 2 critical operations that need to be done.

1. Apply angular acceleration (how do you add a angular acceleration (presumably in the same data type) to your angular velocity?)
2. Calculate the velocity of a point on the rigidbody taking into account both angular and linear velocity.

I have looked at how physics engines like bullet handle it but the math is very confusing and some of the operator overloads seem to hide what is actually going on.

Answers are preferred in C++ or C but as long as the math is clear anything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Data Structures

First some data structures.

#### Linear Algebra

I assume there are `Vector3` classes for 3 valued vectors and `Quaternion` classes for 4 valued rotations as well as `Matrix3` for 3×3 inertia and rotations and other operations. Each obeys its corresponding rules of linear algebra (addition `+`, subtraction `-`, scaling `*`, and products `*`). Each object has its own rules on how to handle these operators. It might be a scale operation, or a matrix-vector product, or a quaternion product depending on the context.

#### Body Properties

Each body has a scalar mass *m*, and a body mass moment of inertia tensor **I_body** which are used in the equations of motion. You also should keep the inverse inertia **I_body_inv** = inverse( **I_body** ).

#### Body State

The current state of the body, contains its position **r** (`Vector3`), orientation **q** (`Quaternion`) and motion. But commonly instead of storing the two velocity vectors (translational **v** (`Vector3`), rotational **ω** (`Vector 3`)), the two momentum vectors are stored (linear **p** (`Vector 3`), angular **L** (`Vector 3`)). Each summed at the center of mass.

The state vector has 13 components since each vector has 3 and the quaternion **q** has 4

**Y** = [ **r**, **q**, **p**, **L** ]

You can choose to make **Y** an array/vector, or a `struct` with appropriate operators to perform linear algebra with.

#### Motion Extraction

Given **Y** you can always extract the translational velocity **v** and angular velocity **ω** of the body with the following algorithm

```
[v, ω] = GetMotion(Y)
// Get Motion from Y=[r, q, p, L]

r = Y[0:2];
q = Y[3:6];
p = Y[7:9];
L = Y[10:12];

// Get 3×3 rotation matrix R from orientation q
R = rotation(q);

// Get 3×3 inverse mass moment of inertia on the world frame
I_inv = R * I_body_inv * transpose(R);

// Get translational velocity vector
v = p / m;

// Get rotational velocity vector
ω = I_inv * L;

return [v, ω];
```

The reverse is also needed to set the initial conditions of the body

```
Y = GetState(r, q, v, ω)
// Get state vector from position & motion

// Get 3×3 rotation matrix R from orientation q
R = rotation(q);

// Get 3×3 mass moment of inertia on the world frame
I = R * I_body * transpose(R);

// Get translational momentum vector
p = m * v;

// Get angular momentum vector
L = I * ω;

return [r, q, p, L];
```

### Integration

At each time step the applied load vectors (force **F**, torque **τ**) change the body state vector.

#### Body State Rate

The time rate of the body state, I call **Y'**, is calculated as follows

```
Y' = GetRate(t, Y)
// Assemble the time rate of the body state Y at time t

r = Y[0:2];
q = Y[3:6];
p = Y[7:9];
L = Y[10:12];

// Get the motion of the body
[v, ω] = GetMotion(Y);

// Get the loading
[F, τ] = GetLoading(t, r, q, v, ω);

r' = v
q' = 0.5*quaterion(ω)*q
p' = F
L' = τ

return [r', q', p', L'];
```

where `quaternion(ω) = [ωx,ωy,ωz,0]` and quaterion product `*` is per quaternion rules.

#### Runge-Kutta 4

It is common to integrate over time using the RK4 method

```
ΔY = GetStep(t, Y, h)
// Integrate state vector Y, over time step h at time t

K0 = GetRate(t, Y);
K1 = GetRate(t+h/2, Y + h/2*K0);
K2 = GetRate(t+h/2, Y + h/2*K1);
K3 = GetRate(t+h, Y + h*K2);

return h/6*(K0 + 2*K1 + 2*K2 + K3);
```

### Simulation

A simulation is the integration of the state vector over many finite time steps.

#### Body Loading

A loading function that describes the forces/torques on each body at each time frame is needed to evaluate the state rate

```
[F,τ] = GetLoading(t, r, q, v, ω)
// Describe the force vector F, and torque vector τ
// from time t, position r, orientation q,
// velocity v, and rot. velocity ω
```

#### Simulation Loop

And the simulation loop integrates until the target time is reached

```
Y = GetState(r, q, v, ω);
time = 0;
while(time<target_time)
{
    Y += GetStep(time, Y, h);
    time += h;
}
```

And there you have the basics of a single rigid body simulation.

#### Post Processing

When you have the body state **Y** you get the motion of the center of mass with `[v, ω] = GetMotion(Y)`. But to answer the second question you need to the velocity of an arbitrary point **v_A**. The point is located with vector **r_A**

```
v_A = GetVelocityAtPoint(Y, r_A)
// Get velocity of world point A
r = Y[0:2]    
[v, ω] = GetMotion(Y)

return v + cross(ω, r_A - r);
```

If you want the velocity of a point **v_B** riding on the body, and defined by a local vector **r_B_body** then

```
v_B = GetVelocityAtBodyPoint(Y, r_B_body)
// Get velocity of body point B
r = Y[0:2]    
q = Y[3:6]
R = rotation(q)
r_A = r + R*r_B_body
return GetVelocityAtPoint(Y, r_A)
```

---

Note that over many steps, the orientation `Quaternion` **q** might drift from a unit quaternion and it would need to be re-normlized.

```
q = normalize(q)
// m = sqrt(qx^2+qy^2+qz^2+qw^2)
// q = q/m
```

In my experience, the drifting away from a unit quaternion does not get progressively worse, as it tends to drift away and then drift back to a unit quaternion, and the resulting error in orientation angle is actually pretty small.

Comment: I forgot to answer the second question. See post-processing paragraph above.

Comment: Wow this is a great answer. I had to change the accepted answer but these are both great!

Comment: Yeah, I will this is by far the answer, detailed and to the point. You'll have to study a lot (as I'm doing now to refresh my simulation courses).

Comment: @neobits - My implementation of the above in C# [on GitHub](https://github.com/ja72/JA.MBD/blob/main/Dynamics/Simulation.cs)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reading the paper *An Introduction to Physically Based Modeling: Rigid Body Simulation I—Unconstrained Rigid Body Dynamics* by David Baraff.

In the paper you have the model of the angular momentum `L` of the rigid body and the angular velocity `ω`. But it does not use the angular acceleration, since the angular momentum depends on the torque being applied to it. You'll also need to define your own Inertia tensor `I(t)` that "describes how the mass in a body is distributed relative to the body’s center of mass." In the paper there's also an implementation of the whole model (mass, forces, torque, angular momentum) in C language.

This repo also has an implementation (in C) of the paper: [RiBOEngine](https://github.com/neobits/RiBOEngine/blob/master/RigidBodyEngine/src/Core/Simulator.cpp)

Source: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf)

In the bullet3 physics engine, the implementation is very similar to the paper describe above. If you look in the `btRigidBody::integrateVelocities()` [method](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/f0f2a952e146f016096db6f85cf0c44ed75b0b9a/src/BulletDynamics/Dynamics/btRigidBody.cpp#L372), you'll find out that in order to calculate the angular velocity you need the tensor and the torque to compute it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I actually found this paper hours after posting this question. Frankly it's slightly too complicated but the implementation solves that.
If anyone else is looking qu3e engine https://github.com/RandyGaul/qu3e is a much easier read than bullet physics and I ended up modifying that engine to suit my needs

Comment: And don't forget https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf